# Org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 1834

Tags: java, android, json

I am fetching the data from webservice, which I am parsing to JSON string. 
 While parsing I am this exception: "org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 1834"

my code is,

```
String jsonstring=getJSONString(response);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
```

The string is,

```
[{"LotDescription":"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village, you&rsquo;ll enjoy:&nbsp; Parks, playgrounds"}]
```

It is parsing till the word "Village" and the raising the exception while parsing " you’ll " which seems to be some HTML content.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you try to analyse yourself? Try to check and debug at least. Every time we will not spoon feed you.

Comment: @Paresh!! Thanks for your advice!! Please dont mind!! I don't have enough time to do so, I am lagging behind so much functionality and so asking and that too I am a newbee to android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add character `\`.

```
[{"LotDescription":\"David Weekley homes Traditional Collection in Baxter Village offers floor plans featuring innovative design and unsurpassed quality. This charming community combines work, play and living, all within the Village. In Baxter Village, you&rsquo;ll enjoy:&nbsp; Parks, playgrounds\"}]
```

This will do.

Comment: I'm confused; why escape that quote?

Answer (score 2):

Your Json is not an `JSONObject` but a `JSONArray`.
Try this instead:

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
        for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject object = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

             String LotDescription = menuObject.getString("LotDescription");
         }
```

Comment: start++ is mistypo to be ignored. Thanks for pointing it out.